# What does an "empty line with semicolon" mean in C#?

Tags: c#, syntax

I stumbled upon this code, and was wondering why the C# compiler raises no warnings or errors.  Strictly speaking, I guess I'm trying to execute nothing which is in fact valid? (for the empty lines)

[image: semi colons on blank lines]

Comment: Yes, that's valid.

Comment: Useful to add breakpoints too (if you're running in debug mode without compilation optimizations) although the times in which I would need to do so are pretty rare.

Comment: Also valid in C++ of course.

Comment: some compilers also will remove some lines of code for optimization (its an option to do this in visual studio)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's an **empty statement**. It is useful as a loop body:

```
while(!Condition()) ;
```

More common in for-loops where the loop body is embedded fully in the loop header.

Let's traverse to the last element of a linked list:

```
Node current = head;
for (; current.Next != null; current = current.Next) ;
return current;
```

It looks a little nasty and generally I prefer writing a longer but more readable loop instead. C++ people tend to cram stuff into the loop header a lot.

I'm sure it can come in handy in code-generation scenarios as well.